# Where does Mirth Listen for HL7 acknowledgement messages?

Tags: tcp, hl7, mirth

I have a mirth channel that listens to a source and then deploys the inbound communications to several channels.   One of these channels sends the HL7 to an application I am developing, and I do not know where to send my ack message. Should I send it to the inbound port of the original message, or does MIRTH have a specific process for sending acknowledgements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acknowledgements in Mirth are handled in destination's *Response Transformer*. To get there, go to the *Destinations* tab, select your destination if there are more than one, under *Channel Tasks* menu on the left side select *Edit Response*. The *msg* variable there is your response message. To generate an acknowledgement use *Postprocessor* script or place your acknowledgement into *responseMap* directly and configure the *Response* setting of the *Source* connector.